# Java: Issue combining Generics, Inner class, and "implements"

Tags: java, generics, inner-classes, implements

I am having an issue combining generics, `implements`, and inner classes.
I am creating a `LinkedBinaryHeap` class which contains an inner class. This inner class is the generic `HeapNode` which extends the generic `Node` class I created; it just adds a variable and methods for a key/priority.

In `LinkedBinaryHeap` I create a generic `LinkedList` to store `HeapNode`s.
I am assuming the generic data being stored extends `Comparable` class.

Here is a layout of what stores what:

```
BinaryHeap->LinkedList(Nodes)->HeapNode(extends Node)->DATA,KEY
```

**My issue is that when declaring the `LinkedList`:**

```
LinkedList<HeapNode> heap;
```

eclipse underlines `HeapNode` and gives me the error:

```
Bound mismatch: The type LinkedBinaryHeap.HeapNode is not a 
valid substitute for the bounded parameter > 
of the type LinkedList
```

I *think* the error is telling me that `HeapNode` must implement the `Comparable`, however my `Node` class implements `Comparable`, so that is taken care of, correct?

I have tried all sorts of different things, but nothing seems to work, the below code is the closest I came. Note that I *have* tried leaving `implements Comparable Node<T>` off the `HeapNode` inner class, and it changes nothing.

Code:

LinkedBinaryHeap.java:

```
public class LinkedBinaryHeap<E extends Comparable<E>> {
    private LinkedList<HeapNode> heap;

    public LinkedBinaryHeap(){
        heap = new LinkedList<HeapNode>();
    }

    /* INNER CLASS DECLARATION. */
    private class HeapNode extends Node<E> implements Comparable<Node<E>>{
        int key;
        public HeapNode(int key, E data){
            super(data);
            this.key = key;
        }

        public int getKey(){
            return key;
        }

        public void setKey(int key){
            this.key = key;
        }
    }
}
```

Node.java:

```
public class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<Node<T>>{
    protected T data;
    protected Node<T> next;
    protected Node<T> previous;

    public Node(T data){
        next = null;
        previous = null;
        this.data = data;
    }   

    /* Some other methods left out here. */

    public int compareTo(Node<T> node) {
        return data.compareTo(node.getData());
    }
}
```

LinkedList.java:

```
public class LinkedList<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<LinkedList<T>>{
    private Node<T> head;
    private Node<T> tail;
    private int size;

    public LinkedList(){
        head = null;
        tail = null;
        size = 0;
    }

    /* Other methods left out. */

    public int compareTo(LinkedList<T> list){
        // does stuff.
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there some reason `LinkedList` and `Node` need to implement Comparable? It's really very awkward to have everything bounded everywhere like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your definitions:

1. `HeapNode` is a subtype of `Node<E>` but `implements Comparable<Node<E>>`
2. `LinkedList` requires a type argument such that `T implements Comparable<T>`
3. i.e. a `LinkedList<HeapNode>` requires that `HeapNode implements Comparable<HeapNode>`
4. which it does not (from (1), above, it `implements Comparable<Node<E>>`)

So the two are not compatible.

You need, in `LinkedList`, to express the node type as a type parameter, bounded appropriately, and the node type's component type parameter as well, also bounded appropriately:

```
public class LinkedList<N extends Node<E>, 
                        E extends Comparable<E>> 
  implements Comparable<LinkedList<N, E>>{
  private N head;
  private N tail;
  private int size;
  ...
```

Now your `LinkedBinaryHeap` needs to adjust it's use of `LinkedList`:

```
public class LinkedBinaryHeap<E extends Comparable<E>> {
  private LinkedList<HeapNode, E> heap;

  public LinkedBinaryHeap(){
      heap = new LinkedList<HeapNode, E>();
  }
```

That should now compile. Whether it achieves your goals of comparing everything to everything else is harder to say!

Comment: Thank you! I wound up taking out implementing Comparable from Node and LinkedList, but I still needed it in HeapNode to be able to store it in LinkedList (for sorting).

Answer (score 0):

LinkedList requires that T implements Comparable. HeapNode implements `Comparable<Node<E>>`. HeapNode != Node so it doesn't satisfy the type bound. Change LinkedList's declaration to `T extends Comparable<? super T>`. This is fine, type-wise: HeapNode is declaring that it can compare itself with any Node or subtype of Node. Of course, this means that HeapNode needs to override `compareTo`, but you're kind of stuck there, what with Node already implementing Comparable.

Edit: as comments point out, this answer is wrong, and not worth fixing because there's a right answer. Let it stay for posterity as a lesson in...something. How I'm not as knowledgeable on generics as I'd like to be, maybe.

Comment: That won't work. I bet `Node<T> head` and `tail` now give a compiler error due to mismatched bounds.

Comment: @AndyBrown Well actually it could work, they would just have to change all the declarations to match.

Comment: @Radiodef. It may work but not as written , and I think it will need more than just changes to `head` and `tail`. (We may possibly be violently agreeing with each other).